# How to get a new UK Driver's licence while travelling?

Tags: uk, driving-licenses

So hypothetically my driver's licence is lost (quite likely).  I'm not in the UK.  Is there any way I can get a replacement one from overseas and get it sent to either me, or a friend in the UK who can forward it on?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're permanently abroad, then [the DVLA cannot issue you a driving licence](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/Diol1/MotoringDecisionTrees/DuplicateLicences/replacement_driving_licence.dsb?DPF0=&DPF1=2&vgsubmit=%C2%A0+Next%C2%A0+).

Otherwise, if you are temporarily abroad, you will need to enclose a signed letter with your full name, date of birth, the UK address on your licence, and your address. This goes along with your D1 application and you will get your new licence mailed to you. Applies if:

- [You had a paper licence](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/Diol1/MotoringDecisionTrees/DuplicateLicences/replacement_driving_licence.dsb?DPF0=1-&DPF1=1&vgsubmit=%C2%A0+Next%C2%A0+)
- [You had a plastic photocard and either the photocard or paper licence was lost](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/Diol1/MotoringDecisionTrees/DuplicateLicences/replacement_driving_licence.dsb?DPF0=1-0-&DPF1=0&vgsubmit=%C2%A0+Next%C2%A0+)
- [You had a plastic photocard and lost both the photocard and paper licence, and need to make changes to your information](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/Diol1/MotoringDecisionTrees/DuplicateLicences/replacement_driving_licence.dsb?DPF0=1-0-1-&DPF1=0&vgsubmit=%C2%A0+Next%C2%A0+)
- [You had a plastic photocard and lost both the photocard and paper licence, do not need to make changes to your information, but do not have a Visa/Mastercard/Eurocard/Maestro credit or debit card](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/Diol1/MotoringDecisionTrees/DuplicateLicences/replacement_driving_licence.dsb?DPF0=1-0-1-1-&DPF1=1&vgsubmit=%C2%A0+Next%C2%A0+)

If you lost both the plastic photocard and the paper licence, do not need to make changes, and have a Visa/Mastercard/Eurocard/Maestro credit or debit card, you will still need to send the letter. However, you do not need to fill out a D1; instead, you can make the request [over the phone](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/Diol1/MotoringDecisionTrees/DuplicateLicences/replacement_driving_licence.dsb?DPF0=1-0-1-1-&DPF1=0&vgsubmit=%C2%A0+Next%C2%A0+) by calling +44 (0)1792 782 341 between 8.00 am and 8.30 pm Monday to Friday and 8.00 am to 8.30 pm on Saturday.

If you want to be doubly sure that I've got everything right, [here's the interactive tool](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/Diol1/MotoringDecisionTrees/DuplicateLicences/replacement_driving_licence.dsb).

Comment: well, couldn't get more complete an answer than that, unless you'd actually done the application for me! +1 and accepted.

Comment: I love that their link to an ordering form (from the interactive tool) is broken...

Comment: This is now out of date given the [demise of the paper counterpart](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/driving-licence-changes?utm_source=counterpart-licence&utm_medium=internal-link&utm_campaign=driving-licence-changes).

Comment: What's the difference between "permanently" abroad and "temporarily" abroad?

Comment: @JonathanReez typically, legal or tax residency or the lack of a UK address largely indicates the difference between permanent (even if its only long term and not actually permanent permanent) and temporary.

Answer (score 7):

If you are a UK tourist in Europe, the EU site also has some information - e.g. lost/stolen licence: contact the local police and then talk to the embassy/consulate (for the UK, they'll just refer you to the DVLA).
http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/driving-licence/driving-licence-loss-theft-replacement/index_en.htm

If your licence was stolen, you'll need a Police report (reference/copy) regardless of *where* it occurred (UK or abroad).

Please note the DVLA stopped issuing paper counterpart licences on 8th June 2015. If you've got your *licence number*, *postcode* and *national insurance number* to hand/noted down somewhere (you need all 3), you can use this to retrieve your licence information as a digital or a paper copy using the "View or share licence details" online tool on the .gov.uk site.

Follow the links at https://www.gov.uk/browse/driving/driving-licences

You can usually use the online process on the .gov.uk site to apply for a new/replacement licence (use the **interactive tool** in the answer above, the link redirects to the new site) or by phone.

The number below can be called from abroad by substituting the first `0` with `+44`, e.g. `0044 300 790 6801`

> You can contact DVLA to apply by phone if none of your details have changed.
>   **DVLA driver licensing enquiries**
>   Telephone: 0300 790 6801
>   Monday to Friday, 8am to 7pm
>   Saturday, 8am to 2pm

also, from the .gov.uk Driving abroad page - just to emphasise there are no immediate changes to the processes involved when travelling in the EU:

> There has been no change to the rights and status of EU nationals in the UK, and UK nationals in the EU, as a result of the referendum.